# StoryBoards are not in compile sources of my project

Tags: ios, xcode

Why can't I locate my storyboards in compile sources in my project? Even a small change in the storyboard takes a lot of time in compiling, this makes me think that there is some Compiler Level Optimisation involved. Am I wrong? I can only find them in Copy Bundle Resources.

More clearly, I'm trying to understand how compiling, linking, and other actions happens when I'm running my project.

Comment: if you have some unused `xib` files in your project, remove them form `Build Phases`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Log Navigator:

[image]

It shows you plenty of information about what is happening when you perform clean, build or run, for example the storyboard processing looks like this:
[image]

From here you can research what this tool does from [the man pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ibtool.1.html).

The nib and storyboard files used to be at the copy resources phase, during the build Xcode performs required operations based on their settings (you can see a set of arguments applied at the command line).